# Fluxo de trabalho (workflow) Git usando GitHub?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, github

Preciso aprender como clonar um projeto do github, para meu computador local e, depois de fazer as alterações necessárias, enviar as modificações de volta para o projeto remoto. Basicamente o *workflow* do git usando GitHub.

Estou usando o linux (ubuntu) e gostaria de realizar as operações via terminal. Já configurei o acesso ao github via SSH.

Agradeceria muito, se a explicação for bem detalhada.

Comment: Veja se isto lhe ajuda: https://try.github.io

Comment: Isto me ajuda a aprender git, tanto que já completei os exercícios deste site. Gostaria de saber como é o fluxo de trabalho usando o github via terminal linux.

Comment: Para um fluxo de trabalho mais completo gosto de usar o [gitflow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.pt_BR.html). Talvez inclua uma resposta com ele, mas se alguém se habilitar...

Comment: @gmsantos se animar, pode colocar sim. Toda boa resposta é bem vinda! ;)

Comment: Estou no trabalho agora, e aqui não tenho acesso pra usar ele, só em casa :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Documentação

Vou fazer uma breve explicação, mas sempre que houver dúvida, consulte a [documentação do Git](http://git-scm.com/doc).

Recomendo estes links com boas explicações sobre a pergunta:

- [Git - Guia Prático](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html)
- [Noções Básicas de Git](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Primeiros-passos-No%C3%A7%C3%B5es-B%C3%A1sicas-de-Git)
- [GitHub Guides](https://guides.github.com/)

### Clonar o Repositório Remoto

A primeira coisa a fazer é clonar o repositório remoto no local desejado usando o [git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) conforme exemplos abaixo:

```
git clone git@github.com:nomeusuario/nomeprojeto.git
```

ou

```
git clone https://github.com/nomeusuario/nomeprojeto.git
```

### Fluxo de Trabalho (*Workflow*)

O *workflow* básico do Git pode ser descrito assim:

1. Você modifica arquivos no seu diretório de trabalho (*working directory*).
2. Você seleciona os arquivos, adicionando snapshots deles para sua área de
   preparação (*staging area*). Para isto você usa o [git add](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).
3. Você faz um commit, que leva os arquivos como eles estão
   na sua área de preparação e os armazena permanentemente no seu
   diretório Git (*repository*). Usando o [git commit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois do `commit`, seus arquivos ainda não foram para o repositório do GitHub. Para subir os arquvivos você usa o comando [git push](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/), conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
git push origin master
```

Para entender melhor o push para o GitHub recomendo ver esta pergunta [Pushing from local repository to GitHub hosted remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573957/pushing-from-local-repository-to-github-hosted-remote) do Stack Overflow.

### Tutorial Prático

Conforme indicado nos comentários da pergunta, um tutorial prático que pode ajudar a entender os principais conceitos do git é o [Git Tutorial](https://try.github.io/).

Answer (score 3):

Antes de tudo crie um repositório local na pasta de preferência com:

```
git init
```

Isso irá criar um .git na pasta para que o git reconheça como repositório.

O fluxo que aprendi foi esse:

Clone o repositório:

```
git clone https://github.com/meunome/meurepositorio
```

Após isso o fluxo é o seguinte, tem o "Working Directory" que é onde seus arquivos estão, o "Index" que é a area temporária (onde você vai utilizar o git add) e o "HEAD" que é como se fosse a área que envia de volta para o repositório online.

Você basicamente faz as alterações onde quiser, adiciona as mudanças com o:

```
git add *
```

E depois comita para o "HEAD":

```
git commit -m "comentários das alterações"
```

Ele estará no "HEAD", para enviar de volta para o repositório de origem:

```
git push origin master
```

É um exemplo bem genérico que eu coloquei, baseado no guia em pt-br, mas foi assim que aprendi.

Fonte: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html

Comment: Cara, muito bom. obrigado. Vou colocar também uma resposta mais detalhada que achei em outro site.

Comment: Por que inicializar um repositório de algo que será, logo depois, clonado? Só seria necessário iniciar um repositório local para já ir trabalhando e depois associá-lo a um remoto, não?